# Utilities.jsonStringify and object methods

Tags: google-apps-script

I haven't found a way yet to properly handle methods in objects when calling Utilities.jsonStringify().  Basically, I cannot use my object after I retrieve it from the CacheService and apply Utilities.jsonParse() to it.

Does anyone have a hint ?

Thanks in advance.

Marc

Comment: Is your JSON properly formatted ? A piece of code that illustrates the problem will be more helpful. I've used CacheService with objects and JSON successfully and haven't had problems.

Comment: It would be a bit long to copy/paste but never mind as I probably hit another limitation of GAS : I cannt store large objects in the CacheService.  I will try with the ScriptDB...

Comment: Oh by the way, I solved the problem (just to hit the size limit) by passing the stored object to the class constructor so that it can copy the attributes from the cached instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json does not include functions when stringifying/parsing. You have to use something homebrewn like:

```
function func2String(obj) {
  var res={};
  for (x in obj) {
    var value=obj[x];
    res[x]=(typeof(value)=='function')?value.toString():value;
  }
  return res;
}
function string2Func (obj) {
  var res={};
  for (x in obj) {
    var value=obj[x];
    if(typeof(value)!='string') {
      res[x]=value;
    }
    else {
      res[x]=(value.substring(0,9)=='\nfunction')?eval('('+value+')'):value;
    }  
  }
  return res;
}
```

usage:

```
var obj=string2Func (Utilities.jsonParse(q.diff));
var str=Utilities.jsonStringify(func2String(diff));
```

Of course the unpacked funcs lost all their closures.